# Differences between weekNumber in Mongo and Luxon

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, luxon

I am doing some mongo aggregations on dates and have run in to an interesting problem, namely that the $week returned from mongo is different than the weekNumber returned from Luxon.

In the below code snippets, the $week from mongo returns 47, whereas the weekNumber from Luxon returns 48.

Is there a way to normalize the two so that a given date will return the same $week/weekNumber?

I can subtract one from the value returned by Luxon, but I'd like to understand why the responses are different in order to determine if there is a more appropriate/elegant way to fix this.

**MONGO**:

```
[{
    '$match': {
        'date': {
            '$eq': datetime(2020, 11, 23, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
          }
        }
    }, {
    '$project': {
        'w': {
            '$week': '$date'
        }
    }
}]
```

**LUXON**:

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

var week = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(2020,10,23)).weekNumber;
console.log(week);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at documentation:

[weekNumber:](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-get-weekNumber)

> Week calendar: For ISO week calendar attributes, see the weekYear, weekNumber, and weekday accessors.

[$week:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/index.html)

> Returns the week of the year for a date as a number between 0 and 53.
>
> Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. This behavior is the same as the “%U” operator to the strftime standard library function.

If you like to get to Week number according to ISO-8601 use [$isoWeek():](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isoWeek/)

> Returns the week number in ISO 8601 format, ranging from 1 to 53. Week numbers start at 1 with the week (Monday through Sunday) that contains the year’s first Thursday.

Looks like in Luxon does not have an equivalent to MongoDB's `$week`

Comment: Thank you, Wernfried! $isoWeek() is perfect.